# List all (exported) objects in all attached environments

Tags: r

I'm curious if there's some convenient function that I'm missing that readily lists all available functions/objects in all attached packages.

Here's what I did that works:

```
lapply(lapply(search(), as.environment), ls, all = TRUE)
```

But that struck me as a bit long-winded. Unless this operation is more uncommon than I'm imagining.

Of course I can just assign

```
super_ls <- function(...) lapply(lapply(search(), as.environment), ls, all = TRUE)
```

But I'm mainly interested if a function like this (with perhaps some nice bells and whistles) is hidden somewhere in the deep dusty corners of `base`.

My original goal was to find the total number of objects attached by default when opening RStudio, i.e., `length(unlist(super_ls()))` (currently 3,140 for the curious).